# Firebase-admin deal with multiple environments

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm pretty new to firebase-admin (and firebase in general).

I have a project on Firebase called X and I created 2 android apps inside `prod` and `dev`.

To initialize my nodejs firebase-admin, I'm passing the service-account.json downloaded from the firebase console. At first I thought I would have one per each app, but it seems that it is a the project level.

I want to send push notifications using the `messaging` feature, it works fine but I'm not sure to what environment I'm sending it (I'm not the android dev, just nodejs).

My question is, how do I initialize the firebase-admin so that it points to `prod` or `dev` ? I usually use env variables for this kind of stuff, but I don't know what to pass to the `initializeApp()` function.

I've tried https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_multiple_apps but I don't see where I can specify `dev` or `prod` apps ?

That's how I initialize it so far :

```
const app = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

...

app.messaging().send(message)
 .then((response) => {
     // Response is a message ID string.
     console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error sending message:', error);
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: are u using cloud functions?

Comment: All I would be using would be `app.messaging().send` so far

Comment: yeah but the question is more, where is your back end? on a firestore cloud function or do u use any other implementation?

Comment: If you have different development environments, you're supposed to create different projects and add the apps to them separately.  It's almost never appropriate for them to share the same project.  If you do this, then you have entirely different credentials for each project to init the admin SDK.

Comment: I'm coding in NodeJS with my own server and using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin

Comment: as Doug mentioned, I recommend you to create 2 different projects, export the sdk key for each one and instantiate your project according

Comment: Ok thanks, so this is the recommended way? Create one project per environment? I have dev, qa, stage, prod, so 4 projects total and in each of them one android app? If yes, post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a project per each environment you use, this is common practice.

Depends on your use case for each you might select different pricing plans.

Export the sdk key for each one, you can instantiate based on environment variables or any other technique that might be useful for you.

Comment: can you please add some code as an example?